# JAVA : factorise code -> runnable anonymous class

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, anonymous-class

i would like factorise my code because i really have a huge same block of code in two class. But they are in anonymous runnable class , so here is a description of my situation

```
class A {
    A(){}
    do_A_function(){}
}
class B extends A{
    B(){
        Runnable runB=new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    super.do_A_function();
                    do_B_function();                    
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runB).start();
    }

    do_B_function(){}
}
class C extends A{

    C(){
        Runnable runC=new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    super.do_A_function();
                    do_C_function();                    
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runC).start();
    }

    do_C_function(){}
}
```

and as you can guess i would like something like that

```
class A {
    A(){
        Runnable runC=new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    do_A_function();
                    do_C_function() OR do_B_function();
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runA).start();

    }
    do_A_function(){}
}

class B extends A{
    B(){
        super();
    }
    do_B_function(){}
}

class C extends A{
    C(){
        super();
    }
    do_C_function(){}
}
```

maybe with an argument in the super() call , but there is no Function Pointers in Java , and i do not want to do reflection if it's possible.

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Listener listener;

    public MyRunnable(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            doA();
            listener.callback()
        }
    }
}

public interface Listener {
    void callback();
}

class B implements Listener {
    B() {
        new Thread(new MyRunnable(this)).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void callback() {
        do_B_function();
    }

    public void do_B_function(){}
}
```